# Tackling The Notch. What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: html, css, ios, google-chrome, mobile

Making a little site for my friend's bar but I can't figure out why I can't push past the "notch" in Chrome. Safari looks ok on mobile but Chrome has that hideous white space.

So far it seems like "initial-scale=1" prohibits the site from pushing past the "notch/cut" in chrome (landscape mode).

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

 #siteWrapper {
  margin-left: 16px env(safe-area-inset-left);
  margin-right: 16px env(safe-area-inset-right);
}
```

[flamningo.steeple.xyz](http://flamingo.steeple.xyz/)

[Here it is pushing past the "notch" on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ol2h.png)

[Here it is being affected by the "notch" in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrzva.png)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the issue so it is easier to diagnose?

Comment: What notch are you referring to?

Comment: Does Chrome give you the desired behaviour if you follow the [instructions here](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/08/chrome-69-beta-av1-video-decoder-css.html)? (see *Display Cutouts*)

Comment: @ChaseSmith I edited my original post with some screenshots.

Comment: @GeneSy I edited my original post with some screenshots.

Comment: @Marijan I reformatted my meta tags to ONLY what is in that tutorial and it now works in chrome (landscape)--but other things are now messed up in Chrome and Safari--but it's a start. Think I'm starting to pinpoint the problem--something in my metatags.

Comment: @AustinAllen A shot in the dark: Did you try implementing two `viewport`meta tags?

Comment: @Marijan I did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I narrowed things down to the "initial-scale=1" in the meta tag. Not sure why, probably some funky CSS or JS.

Tried some different numbers:

0.9 seems to be a nice fit between chrome and safari in landscape and portrait.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.9, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no">

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
#siteWrapper {
margin-top: 16px env(safe-area-inset-top);
margin-left: 16px env(safe-area-inset-left);
margin-bottom: 16px env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
margin-right: 16px env(safe-area-inset-right);
  }}
```